# What can I do to protect my application's data from other applications running on the same user?

Tags: linux, security, rust, sandbox

In a typical Linux application, every software gets the same privileges to my files as my user. This is often way more than what they need in order to do their job.

What facilities are there for limiting this in Linux (and other Unixes and Windows)?

Case in point, I'm writing [a lightweight password hasher/manager](https://github.com/vegai/chaos) and wonder what could I do to secure the master key and database without requiring user input.

Comment: If no user input is required, what stops another application just running the password manager itself and/or deriving any encryption keys in the same way as the password manager? It seems to me that the only truly reliable way to handle this is to encrypt the files using some secret that isn't (entirely) stored on the computer e.g. a password the user enters (at some point).

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on how much control you have over the user's system. Can you configure the kernel, security policies and all software used there?

If yes, then there are things you can do - you could use separate user account, SELinux policies and possibly other OS features to define precisely who and when can access the data.

If no, its game over. You may do some obfuscation and use some tricks to pretend you've put some effort, but you can not solve this problem.